# Android: Start a new activity without showing two activities when Recent Button is clicked

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am using this code to start new activities when I am in an activity:

```
Intent open = new Intent(context.getActivity(), ActivitySecond.class);
context.startActivity(open);
```

When executing this code, the new activity is shown. But when I click on the **Recent Button** on my smartphone, now the new activity and the previous activity are available.
But in many other Android apps for example Whatsapp, if you click on e.g. the Settings Button, you don't see two activities, when clicking on the **Recent Button**.
I don't also think that they all use fragments, but I believe the new ones are also activities.
How have I to implement that?

**EDIT**
Here a full sample:
First my activity_main.xlm:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.mb7.sportappbp.Activity.ActivityMain">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:titleTextColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:title="FIT UP">
        <!--app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"-->


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now the code of the page:

```
public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity {

...
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private final String mainColor = "#2648FF";
public  static  User mainUser ;
public static ActivityMain activityMain;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),this);

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    setTabLayout();
}
...

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    MenuItem item= menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,ActivitySettings.class));
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,ActivitySettings.class));
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

....

}
```

As you can see I call the new Activity in the `onContextItemSelected` or `onOptionsItemSelected` event.

The layout of the new activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Stimmungsabfrage"
    android:key="pref_key_storage_settings">


    <ListPreference
        android:title="Abstand der Stimmungsabfrage"
        android:key="lstStmabfrageAbstand"
        android:defaultValue="3"
        android:summary="%s"
        android:entries="@array/ArrrayStmabfrageAbstand"
        android:entryValues="@array/ArrrayStmabfrageAbstandeValue" />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Erinnerung an das Training"
    android:key="pref_key_storage_settings">

    <ListPreference
        android:title="Fortbewegungsmittel zum Fitnessstudio"
        android:key="lstVerkehrsmittel"
        android:defaultValue="1"
        android:summary="%s"
        android:entries="@array/ArrrayVerkehrsmittel"
        android:entryValues="@array/ArrrayVerkehrsmittelValue" />
    <Preference
    android:title="Trainingszeiten und Studioadresse"
    android:summary="Wann und wo findet Ihr Training statt?">
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetPackage="com.example.mb7.sportappbp"
        android:targetClass="com.example.mb7.sportappbp.Activity.ActivitySettingInitializer" />
</Preference>
    <Preference
        android:title="Kompass"
        android:summary="Zum Bearbeiten deiner Angaben im Kompass">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetPackage="com.example.mb7.sportappbp"
            android:targetClass="com.example.mb7.sportappbp.Activity.ActivityKompass" />
    </Preference>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

and the code:

```
public class ActivitySettings extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Display the fragment as the main content.
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
            .commit();
}
public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
//        Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityMain.class);
//        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
//        startActivity(i);
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
    Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.activityMain,
            "Erfolgreich gespeichert" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


}
```

Now when I am in `ActivityMain` and go to `ActivitySettings` and click on the **Recent Button**, I will see both activities and this is what I want to prevent.

**EDIT**
Here the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mb7.sportappbp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />

<application
    android:name=".Activity.FireApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/sport_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.ActivityMain"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.ActivityDiaryEntry"
        android:label="Tagebuch Eintrag"
        android:parentActivityName=".Activity.ActivityMain" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.ActivityDiary"
        android:label="Tagebuch"
        android:parentActivityName=".Activity.ActivityMain" />
    <activity android:name=".Activity.ActivitySettings" />
    <activity android:name=".Activity.ActivityStimmungsAbgabe" />
    <activity android:name=".Activity.ActivitySettingInitializer" />
    <activity android:name=".Activity.ActivityChallenge" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.ActivityCategories"
        android:label="Kategorie auswählen..."
        android:parentActivityName=".Activity.ActivityExerciseOverview" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.ActivityExercises"
        android:parentActivityName=".Activity.ActivityCategories" />
    <activity android:name=".Activity.ActivityExerciseOverview" />
    <activity android:name=".Activity.ActivityFragebogen" />
    <activity android:name=".Activity.ActivityFitnessFragebogen" />
    <activity android:name=".Activity.ActivityMotivationMessage" />
    <activity android:name=".Activity.ActivityTrainQuestioning"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity.ActivityKompass"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What you want to see when Recent button clicked?

Comment: I need to see your code for what happens when the recent button is clicked in order to help.

Comment: @JohnJoe Imagine We have been in ActivityOne and now we start ActivitySecond. Then we should only see ActivtiySecond when we click the Recent button. But we don't want to finish ActivityOne, because we want to return to it when clicking the Back button as we are in ActivitySecond. Exactly the same procedure we have in Whatsapp when you are in the main page and then you go to the Settings page

Comment: Then you can implement something in your recent button without using `intent`. Your recent button is the device button, or implemented by you ?

Comment: @JohnJoe The device button

Comment: @ConnorT The question is edited to offer a full sample

Comment: Please post the AndroidManifest.xml file for your app.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Edited and the manifest is available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried replacing "singleInstance" with "singleTask" in AndroidManifest.xml? 
You can already see from docs that "singleInstance" does not give you what you are looking for.

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot